# Total keyboard, mouse and screen lock

Tags: scripts, keyboard, lock-screen

I want to make an alarm script to play a video and lock totally the keyboard, the mouse and the screen until the video finish.

I really need wake up on time and sooner haha

This is all I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ruta al video que deseas reproducir
VIDEO_PATH="/ruta/a/tu/video.mp4"

# Hora a la que deseas que se reproduzca el video (formato HH:MM)
HORA_REPRODUCCION="08:00"

# Obtén la hora actual en formato HH:MM
HORA_ACTUAL=$(date +%H:%M)

# Calcula el tiempo restante hasta la reproducción
TIEMPO_RESTANTE=$(($(date -d "$HORA_REPRODUCCION" +%s) - $(date -d "$HORA_ACTUAL" +%s)))

# Espera hasta la hora de reproducción
sleep $TIEMPO_RESTANTE

# Reproduce el video en pantalla completa usando ffplay
ffplay -autoexit -fs "$VIDEO_PATH"

# Bloquea la pantalla usando xdg-screensaver
xdg-screensaver lock

# Bloquea el teclado usando xtrlock
xtrlock
```